# How to solve $y''-y=\sin(x)$ using power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I was asked to find the solution for this equation around point $x=1$:
$$y''+y=\sin(x)$$
My try:
Let $X=x-1,$ we have:
$$y(X)=\sum_{n=0}c_nX^n\Rightarrow y''(X)=\sum_{n=2}n(n-1)c_nX^{n-2}$$
and also we know:
$$\sin(X+1) =\sum_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{(X+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$
by subsitution in the equation we have:
$$\sum_{n=2}n(n-1)c_nX^{n-2}-\sum_{n=0}c_nX^n = \sum_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{(X+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
we must change the values of first sigma in order to merge left sigmas:
$$\sum_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}X^{n}-\sum_{n=0}c_nX^n = \sum_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{(X+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
so we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}-c_n)X^n = \sum_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{(X+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
I got stuck at this section because I don't know how to equate coefficients for this equation. Any ideas??

Comment: Your series expansion of $\sin x$ is wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is it wrong when I used X?Because we are computing series around x=1 so I used X+1 instead of x.

Comment: $\sin x =x-\frac {{x^{3}}} {3!}+\frac {x^{5}} {5!}+...$. Where does $(x+1)^{2n+1}$ come from?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think because $X=x-1$ so we conclude x is X+1. then $sin(x)=sin(X+1)=(X+1)-(X+1)^3/3! + ...$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The question wanted from me that. I must compute that around x=1 . Not other ways :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\sin (X+1)=\sin X \cos 1+\cos X \sin 1$. Use the series expansions of $\sin X$ and $\cos X$.